# Preventing serialization of a property

Tags: c#, vb.net, serialization

This is a bit more complex than the straight-forward scenarios discussed in other similar questions posted on SO.

I have an hierarchy of classes like this:

- `DrawingObject` (`abstract` class, defines `abstract` properties `Size` and `Location`)

  - `Label` (inherits `DrawingObject`. Provides concrete implementations of `Size` and `Location`. Both properties should be serialized)
  - `Line` (inherits `DrawingObject`. `Size` and `Location` properties should be ignored in serialization/deserialization)

I'm using `DataContractSerializer` to serialize my `DrawingObject`s, which poses the following problem:

- If I do not mark any of the classes with `DataContract`, `IgnoreDataMember` has no effect and `Location`/`Size` properties are serialized for both `Label` and `Line`. Something I don't want.
- If I apply `DataContract` on my classes, a run-time exception is generated telling that `DrawingObject` cannot be marked with `DataContract` because its base class `ObservableObject` (yes, MVVM Light) is not marked with `DataContract` attribute.

What can I do to prevent serialization of these property in one derived class while not in the other?

### Edit

The more I dig, the weirder it gets. Looks like .NET Framework 3.5 changed the rules slightly and `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes are [no longer required](http://blog.zestconsulting.net/?p=11) to make `DataContractSerializer` work. If you omit these attributes, `DataContractSerializer` will serialize all public read/write properties of the class (class must have a public parameter-less constructor). This could be a good news for my scenario, but it seems like C# and VB.NET act a bit differently in this regards:

### C#

The following code serializes correctly:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
  public abstract class DrawingObject
  {
    public abstract string Location { get; set; }
    public abstract string Size { get; set; }
  }

  public class Label : DrawingObject
  {
    public Label() { }

    private string _Loc;
    private string _Sz;

    public override string Location { get { return _Loc; } set { _Loc = value; } }
    public override string Size { get { return _Sz; } set { _Sz = value; } }
  }

  public class Line : DrawingObject
  {
    public Line() { }

    public override string Location { get { return "Line Location"; } set { Console.WriteLine("Line.Location.set"); } }
    public override string Size { get { return "Line Size"; } set { Console.WriteLine("Line.Size.set"); } }
  }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      DrawingObject D1 = new Label() { Location="Label Loc", Size="Label Sz" } ;
      DrawingObject D2 = new Line();

      List<DrawingObject> DObjs = new List<DrawingObject>();
      DObjs.Add(D1);
      DObjs.Add(D2);

      DataContractSerializer S = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<DrawingObject>), new[] { typeof(Line), typeof(Label) }, 0x7FFF, false, true, null);

      var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

      using (var writer = new StringWriter(sb))
      {
        using (var xmlWriter = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(writer, new System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true, OmitXmlDeclaration = false }))
          S.WriteObject(xmlWriter, DObjs);

        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

        Console.Read();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### VB.NET

This code doesn't serialize anything:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

Public MustInherit Class DrawingObject
  Public MustOverride Property Location() As String
  Public MustOverride Property Size() As String
End Class

Public Class Label
  Inherits DrawingObject

  Public Sub New()
  End Sub

  Private _Loc As String
  Private _Sz As String

  Public Overrides Property Location() As String
    Get
      Return _Loc
    End Get
    Set
      _Loc = Value
    End Set
  End Property

  Public Overrides Property Size() As String
    Get
      Return _Sz
    End Get
    Set
      _Sz = Value
    End Set
  End Property
End Class

Public Class Line
  Inherits DrawingObject

  Public Sub New()   
  End Sub

  Public Overrides Property Location() As String
    Get
      Return "Line Location"
    End Get
    Set
      Console.WriteLine("Line.Location.set")
    End Set
  End Property

  Public Overrides Property Size() As String
    Get
      Return "Line Size"
    End Get
    Set
      Console.WriteLine("Line.Size.set")
    End Set
  End Property
End Class

Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    Dim D1 As DrawingObject = New Label() With {.Location = "Label Loc", .Size = "Label Sz"}
    Dim D2 As DrawingObject = New Line()

    Dim DObjs As New List(Of DrawingObject)
    DObjs.Add(D1)
    DObjs.Add(D2)

    Dim S As New DataContractSerializer(GetType(List(Of DrawingObject)), {GetType(Line), GetType(Label)}, &H7FFF, False, True, Nothing)

    Dim sb = New System.Text.StringBuilder()

    Using writer = New StringWriter(sb)
      Using xmlWriter = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(writer, New System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings() With {.Indent = True, .OmitXmlDeclaration = False})
        S.WriteObject(xmlWriter, DObjs)

        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString())
        Console.Read()
      End Using
    End Using
  End Sub

End Module
```

I've tried to make them syntactically equivalent, yet `DataContractSerializer` behaves differently.

### Edit 2

I tested @CodeCaster's suggestion and applied `[IgnoreDataMember]` to the `Location` property of the `Line` object. Doesn't make any difference (`Location` property is still serialized for `Line`). Looks like `DataContractSerializer` does not respects this attribute in derived classes. I also tried serializing Line object directly instead of the parent `List`. `Location` is even then written to the output.

Don't know where to go from here.

### Edit 3

After day-long digging and trying out everything, the difference between c# and VB.NET code above finally turned out to be a problem in flushing the XML writer. Odd thing is that C# code doesn't require me to call `Flush()` after serializing the object, whereas VB.NET produces output only if a `Flush()` call is made after `WriteObject()`.

The other thing I discovered is that `IgnoreDataMember` doesn't have any effect on the overridden members in the derived classes. You must apply the attribute in the base class to make it work, which is of course not possible in my case. Think I'll have to invent some hack around this problem.

Comment: _"If I do not mark any of the classes with DataContract, IgnoreDataMember has no effect"_ - ttry it.

Comment: I did this before applying `DataContract`. `Location` and `Size` were being written to the serialized output.

Comment: That should not happen. Please read [ask] and create a [mcve].

Comment: *"If I do not mark any of the classes with DataContract, IgnoreDataMember has no effect"* - you mean, you put the attribute on the overrides?  Or on the base abstract properties?  As requested, please extend to a [mcve].

Comment: I apply `IgnoreDataMember` on the derived class only and not in the base class obviously because I do not want it to ignore these properties in case of `Label`.

Comment: Let me gather a sample

Comment: @CodeCaster: Added verifiable example.

Comment: @dbc: Added verifiable example.

Comment: You could use protobuf-net which allows you to explicitely declare everything you want to be serialized and what not. Simply switch over to [ProtoContract] [ProtoMember(1...N)] and you should be fine. If in your derived classes you want have have member of a base class serialized which has no contract you can declare dummy property getter setters with a ProtoMember to completely control the serialization of all members.

Comment: The difference between the c# and vb.net code is that, in the c# code, the `Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString())` is outside the inner `using`, but in the vb.net code, it is inside the inner `Using`.  It's the inner `using` that does the flush.

Comment: @dbc: I see. Thanks for pointing out. That leaves us with just the bigger issue.

Answer (score 0):

You must use "KnownType" in order to DataContractSerializer perform the correct serialization, so your base classe need to have DataContract atribute and inform the child class types like the example

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Label))]
public abstract class DrawingObject
{
public abstract string Location { get; set; }
public abstract string Size { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Roger. I have already tried that. Doesn't make a difference. Did you run it with success on your end?